# How can a websocket send instruction to only one particular iot device

Tags: websocket, iot, esp8266

I am quite new to IOT. But I have started working on a home automation project. Where everything else seems to fall in line except for one thing. How do I send data to just one particular device and not broadcasting it. Suppose I a have SocketIO on my server. and a websocket implemented in C for example. this - https://github.com/morrissinger/ESP8266-Websocket

Now suppose if a mobile user wants to turn off the a light, he sends server request to turn off his light, server can identify through user's information the id of the device(Which is stored in database). But now how will server send that particular IOT device instructions to turn off light. How will it discover. 
If I am using that websocket library, it can send requests to the server, but when server wants to send instructions, how will it identify the particular device and only send that device the relevant instructions.

Comment: The IOT device you are using should support an API for communicating with it - built into the device and hub it is connected to.  It is probably not using generic webSocket.  You should use the API that is specific for the IOT device and hub you are using.  In general you will communicate with the hub and the hub will handle the communication to the IOT device itself.

Comment: Thank you, But I am using esp826 module with arduino. And i am not aware of any Specific API. can u please give an example of what kind of API You are talking about. I am aware of socket.io, which has a concept of  rooms. where you can emit a particular event to one particular room. But can u enlighten me a little more about what APIs i can use for my situation with esp826 and arduino. to communicate with a Python Server(Django).

Comment: I'm confused about what exact IOT device you are trying to communicate with and where that device is relative to the software you are running?  Is this IOT device running on your Arduino?  And, is your software on the same Arduino as the IOT device (such that you're just trying to talk directly to the hardware of the IOT device)?  Or is the IOT device remote and you're trying to talk to a remote device?

Comment: I don't know which esp826 module you have, but here's one discussion of talking to it via a serial port: http://www.instructables.com/id/ESP8266-Wi-fi-module-explain-and-connection/step6/Talking-to-the-ESP8266/